# TCP_USER_TIMEOUT at Values below RTT

Tags: tcp

Considering the [description of TCP_USER_TIMEOUT](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/tcp.7.html):

> When the
> value is greater than 0, it specifies the maximum amount of
> time in milliseconds that transmitted data may remain
> unacknowledged before TCP will forcibly close the
> corresponding connection and return ETIMEDOUT to the
> application.

And [this comment from the RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5482#section-3.1):

> Very short USER TIMEOUT values can affect TCP transmissions over
> high-delay paths.  If the user timeout occurs before an
> acknowledgment for an outstanding segment arrives, possibly due to
> packet loss, the connection closes.  Many TCP implementations default
> to USER TIMEOUT values of a few minutes.  Although the UTO option
> allows suggestion of short timeouts, applications advertising them
> should consider these effects.

I'd expect a TCP_USER_TIMEOUT of 2 ms to have catastrophic consequences: in a network where the RTT is less than 2 ms, every TCP packet sent would timeout waiting for an ACK and the connection would be closed. However, in my environment I'm not experiencing this. Connections can be established and data is sent and received fine.  I do notice, however, that if I pull the cord or down the receiving interface, the TCP_USER_TIMEOUT does effectively detect a loss in connection and the connection is closed in a timely fashion. So, TCP_USER_TIMEOUT is working, just not the way I'd expect it to.

What am I misunderstanding about TCP_USER_TIMEOUT? Why don't values lower than RTT cause the connection to be dropped?

In case it's helpful, my client is a Scientific Linux 6.1 box with the 2.6.32 kernel.

Comment: Do you check this scenario with your app or is it some standard tool?

Comment: The app: it logs when the detection has been closed. If the connection were being closed upon every packet being sent, the app would have many failure messages and would not function at all.

Answer (score 1):

UTO implementation in Linux was inaccurate, and has been recently fixed by this patchset:(Just in case you are not the author of this patchset):
https://lkml.org/lkml/2018/7/18/1090

However, even after UTO fired, the host stops retransmit and goes to TCP_CLOSE state but does not reset the connection. It is the responsibility of the application send the RST.